# querySelector after a specific element

Tags: javascript, dom, selectors-api

Is there a way to select elements appearing after a given element using CSS selectors.

Suppose I have a DOM like this one

```
<body>
  <span class="next">A next span</span>
  <div>
    <span class="next target">the target next span</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="next">this is the one I want to select</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

I want to select the `span`s of class `next` but only the ones that appear after `span.next.target`. What make this tricky is that they need not to be siblings or under the same parent node but can appear anywhere in the DOM.

Is this even possible, or am I doomed to stick with a for loop?

Comment: Not possible; as there is no CSS selector that can select parents.

Comment: I know that there is not yet parent css selectors, I'm asking if there is no method other that a for loop to select the next element using a given class.

Comment: Closest thing would be the _next sibling selector_ (http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/) But you're not working with siblings. So `$('.next').each(...)` and  extract those after `.hasClass('target')`.

Comment: @sitifensys: are you looking for a CSS selector or a JavaScript solution?

Comment: @SalmanA I'm looking for a javascript solution other than a for loop.

Comment: @sitifensys: I can think of a jQuery (or JavaScript + querySelectorAll) solution with recursion and a for loop.

Comment: @SalmanA What part of the "other than a for loop" you didn't undersand :)

Comment: With jQuery selectors, you can come pretty close: `$('.next.target ~ .next, .next.target ~ * .next, :has(.next.target) ~ * .next')` means "get me all following sisters, following sister's descendants and ancestors' following sister's descendants with `.next` from `.parent.next`". Unfortunately, native selectors do not support `:has()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain javascript for this:

```
'use strict';

console.clear();
const spanNextNodes = document.querySelectorAll('div span.next');

let find = function*(nodes) {
    let isNextTargetFound = false,
        arrayOfNodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes);       // untill spread operator is supported [...nodes], we have to use slice method

    for (let n of arrayOfNodes) {
        if (isNextTargetFound) {
            yield n;
        } else if (n.classList.contains('target')) {
            isNextTargetFound = true;
        }
    }
}

for (let item of find(spanNextNodes)) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

[Here is an example](http://codepen.io/vlad-bezden/pen/qbmQNb?editors=101)
It's based on ES2015 standards using function generators (yield), but if you would like to use ES5 you can add items to array and return array instead.